# How to console log ("No Result Found")

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have a Search Bar input where the user types and it show results as the user types (Filter) but now I'm trying to show a "No result found" after the user is typing in the input and it didn't show anything

**The Code:**

```
const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([]);
const [searchError, setSearchError] = useState(false);


    const searchItems = (searchValue) => {
        setSearchInput(searchValue)
        setLoading(true)
        setSearchError(false)
        if (searchInput !== '') {
            const filteredData = APIData.filter((post) => {
                return Object.values(post)
                .join('')
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
            })
            setFilteredResults(filteredData)
            
        } else if (!APIData.length){
          setSearchError(true)
        } else {
          setFilteredResults(APIData)
        }
    }
    console.log(searchError)
```

My question is how to console log the error if there is no data matches what the user is typing?